# How to make Listbox's texts center aligned in desktop application using c#.net

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, alignment

Please tell me how can I align center to my ListBox's text in desktop application.
I am using C#.Net in Visual Studio 2005.

I am using Windows forms.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set the `DrawMode` property of the ListBox to `DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed`, which gives you control over the entire graphical representation of each item. For instance:

```
ListBox listBox = new ListBox();
listBox.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
listBox.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(listBox_DrawItem);

    void listBox_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox list = (ListBox)sender;
        if (e.Index > -1)
        {
            object item = list.Items[e.Index];
            e.DrawBackground();
            e.DrawFocusRectangle();
            Brush brush = new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor);
            SizeF size = e.Graphics.MeasureString(item.ToString(), e.Font);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(item.ToString(), e.Font, brush, e.Bounds.Left + (e.Bounds.Width / 2 - size.Width / 2), e.Bounds.Top + (e.Bounds.Height / 2 - size.Height / 2)); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes.  Use TextRenderer.DrawText however.

Answer (score 1):

In WPF you'll use the [Control.HorizontalContentAligment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.horizontalcontentalignment(v=VS.100).aspx) property:

```
<ListBox Name="lstSample" 
         HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
    <ListBoxItem>Item 1</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>Item 2</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>Item 3</ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

In Windows Forms you'll have to draw the content of the ListBox yourself by handling the [DrawItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawitem.aspx) event. Here's an [example on how to do it](http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/441167-align-text-listbox).

Answer (score 0):

use  `TextFormatFlags flags = TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter;`

```
listBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
listBox1.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(listBox1_OnDrawItem);

private void listBox1_OnDrawItem(object sender,DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    TextFormatFlags flags = TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter;
    if (e.Index >= 0)
    {
        e.DrawBackground();
        var textRect = e.Bounds;
        string itemText = DesignMode ? "Custom ListBox" : Items[e.Index].ToString();
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, itemText, e.Font, textRect, e.ForeColor, flags);
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }
}
```