# Listbox String format not the same of the console output

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, listbox, formatting

I have this form who contain a listbox

```
    Public Class Item
    Private sList As List(Of Container)

    Sub New(ByRef sList As List(Of Container))
        InitializeComponent()

        Me.sList = sList
    End Sub

    Private Sub Item_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        For Each c As Container In sList
            ListBox1.Items.Add(c)
        Next


        ListBox1.DataSource = sList
        ListBox1.DisplayMember = "sItem"
    End Sub
End Class
```

This would be the class containter

```
Public Class Container

    Private _sItemName As String
    Private _sPrice As Single
    Private _iNumber As Integer
    Private _sItemString As String

    Sub New(ByVal _sItemName As String, ByVal _sPrice As Single, ByVal _iNumber As Integer, ByVal _sItemString As String)
        Me._sItem = _sItemName
        Me._sPrice = _sPrice
        Me._iNumber = _iNumber
        Me._sItemString = _sItemString
    End Sub

    Public Property sItemName() As String
        Get
            Return _sItemName
        End Get
        Private Set(value As String)
            _sItemName = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property sItemString() As String
        Get
            Return _sItemString
        End Get
        Private Set(value As String)
            _sItemString = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property sPrice() As Single
        Get
            Return _sPrice
        End Get
        Private Set(value As Single)
            _sPrice = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property iNumber() As String
        Get
            Return _iNumber
        End Get
        Private Set(value As String)
            _iNumber = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

And there's where I add it to the output

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dgv As DataGridView = DataGridView1
    Dim rowIndex As Integer = dgv.SelectedRows(0).Index

    Dim _sItem As String = ""
    Dim _iNumber As Integer = TextBox1.Text
    Dim _sPrice As Single = dgv.Rows(rowIndex).Cells("Prix").Value * TextBox1.Text

    Dim format As String = "{0, -10} {1, -10} {2, 5}"

    _sItem = String.Format(format, dgv.Rows(rowIndex).Cells("Nom").Value.ToString, _sPrice.ToString("C2"), _iNumber.ToString)

    Console.WriteLine(_sItem)
    Dim container As New Container(_sItem, _sPrice, _iNumber, dgv.CurrentRow.Cells("Nom").Value.ToString)

    If (updateDGV(container) = True) Then
        sList.Add(container)
    End If

    TextBox1.Clear()
    TextBox1.Focus()
    updateLabel()
End Sub
```

So my question is why the output on the lsitbox is like this
[image]

And the console output is

[image]

What I want is the listbox output be the same as the console but the format seems to not work and I have no idea from there on how I should make this work I could use some help and explanation on why the listbox is not showing the text properly

To be sure i'm clear : Is there a way to make the listbox output look the same of the console output

Edit : ListView

THe things as you can see the data are binded so if I do so

Container Access from listbox

```
        Dim obj As Object = ListBox1.SelectedItem

    If (TypeOf obj Is Container) Then
        Dim c As Container = CType(obj, Container)

        Console.WriteLine(c.iNumber)
    End If
```

it can return me the object when I select one row, that's what I don't know how to do with the list view and the adding ( The for each `Items.add(c)` I don't know the equivalent for a listview)

Comment: You have to make it multicolumn to get the effect you want without hassle. But the performance on the ListBox is not too good on this front (at least, in my opinion). Would you consider a different, although similar-enough control, like ListView?

Comment: @varocarbas
I've kinda tried the listview but it seems I can't make it work the adding the binding I don't know why if you could give me an example with the code I gave you I would be greatfull :P

Comment: There you have a sample code to create/populate a multi-column ListView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As proposed via comment, here comes a multi-column sample code with `ListView`:

```
With ListView1
    .View = View.Details
    .Columns.Add("")
    .Columns.Add("")
    .Columns.Add("")
End With

Dim inputs As List(Of Container) = New List(Of Container)
'populate "inputs"...
For Each item As Container In inputs
    Dim curEntry As New ListViewItem(New String() {item.sItem.ToString(), item.sPrice.ToString(), item.iNumber.ToString()})
    ListView1.Items.Add(curEntry)
Next
```

You can treat each column independently (alignment, width, etc.) via `ListView1.Column(index)`.

Comment: but the data aren't binded, see  EDIT : ListView in my post

Comment: @Mokmeuh OK. What is Container exactly? A list with elements of your container class? I will update my answer by showing you how to populate it in this case.

Comment: If you want an example see the output, and the container class everything is managed from there but now I use a simple string format who cancat everythings but I can add it manually as the container class contain the property for every variable who's listed

Container class I think it's uplaoded ? No I didnt forgot to put it there.

Comment: @Mokmeuh I have updated my answer to show you how to populate the ListView by relying on a multi-propery class as your "Container"

Comment: Ok, and the output would be row based or the column and cell will exist (I would prefer for them not to be there) like a listbox is only 1 row I read myself and I seems confusing, sorry for that what I wonder if I compare a datagrid view who have a property to select a row wherever you click on the row I jsut wonder if the lsit view have something similar

also is the data binded, like I showed you an item selected would contain the actual object it was populated with ?

Comment: @Mokmeuh I am not sure if I am following you. But you have just two options to get the kind of appearance you want: either making sure that the text in each rows follows a regular structure (for example by relying on something on the lines of what Vladimir proposed); or dividing the rows into columns (what I proposed). If you don't want to have columns, I can delete this answer (I understood from your answer to my comment that you would like it).

Comment: Please leave it there it's actually good you gave me a good start I will go from there thank you really helpfull :)

Comment: @Mokmeuh you cannot change other's code (your correction was rejected by all the people who saw it, not by me), next time just write a comment. Also bear in mind that my code is a mere sample, expected to be used by others; for other people, your exact variables do not matter, just the idea (I wrote the names after a really quick look without realising that these were the private variables). Thus, my code was right as far as compiled fine by accounting for the given Class (not exactly yours). I have modified the code as you suggested.

Comment: @Mokmeuh I have re-read your previous comment and the answer is that the cells will not exist. You create the columns with each row (as shown by my code). The reason why I didn't understand it properly before is because you said "listbox is only 1 row" when you probably meant "listbox is only 1 column". The DGV comes from a different structure: it is based on cells (rows and columns on it). In any case, in all the controls you have to insert the given elements (a DGV can also be blank). I hope that now your ideas are clearer. For the future, please, ask as much as you need.

Comment: That was the point :S If I would be in this situation and I can relate to a concrete example in a complete situation with everythings defined
anywyas thankcx

by the way I can't seems to find a way for the item added be the type of container would you have a solution for that ?

Comment: I will create another question and give you the link here, if you are in the modd to give it a shot ^^''

Comment: @Mokmeuh wait. You don't need to create a new question. Is the sample code I wrote not enough for you?

Comment: it's comply enought it's like another problem but in some way related to this one your answer did respond to my question now I would have another question on the binding

Comment: @Mokmeuh OK. Then better write a new question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095107/datasource-of-a-listview

If you want to give a shot, thank you for your help in this problem

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38340/discussion-between-varocarbas-and-mokmeuh)

Answer (score 2):

There is [monospaced font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) in console. But isn't one in widget.

Comment: First [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943330/how-to-make-listboxs-texts-center-aligned-in-desktop-application-using-c-net) is for you.